# How to remove smiley character in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, unicode

I am developing a cross browser/platform application in Html 5. I am using a contentEditable for text insertion. I draw the text inserted by the user on a canvas. When the user input smiley symbols (from Nexus 7 in my case), I am not able to get the width of those characters.

I am putting every character in a non visible div(which I have put at some negative coordinates) and getting div's width and height.

Is there any way I can remove these smileys inserted by the user?

The application also supports other languages like chinese, japanese etc , so I cannot put a check for charCode, unless there is a specific range of unicode for these special characters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If possible, can post "smiley symbol" character , `document` `charset` ? Thanks

Comment: Show your code, explain exactly how it fails, and specify what you mean by “smiley characters”.

Comment: Using the term "emoticon" might be less ambiguous.  OP probably means Unicode codepoints such as  [U+1F600, GRINNING FACE].  Things to check include correct UTF-16 encoding/decoding, font having the codepoint, and browser text rendering supporting the codepoint.